# Test For Final String Salesforce

Tags: class, testing, salesforce, apex

I am working on our coverage and am stuck on writing a test for this method:

METHOD:

```
public static String getUnknownQueryProblemErrorMessage(String message) {
    return unknownQueryProblemErrorMessage + '"' + message + '"';
}
```

TEST:

```
 static testmethod void getUnknownQueryProblemErrorMessage()
{
 String message = Constants.unknownQueryProblemErrorMessage + ' ' + 'message' +' ';
System.AssertEquals(Constants.getUnknownQueryProblemErrorMessage('My Message'),message);  
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: how exactly are you stuck? does the test not compile, not run, fail?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. It didnt compile like that. here was the final solution:       'static testmethod void getUnknownQueryProblemErrorMessage()
    {
    Constants c = new Constants();//instantiate the class
    c.getUnknownQueryProblemErrorMessagemethod(); //call the instance method
    String message = constants.unknownQueryProblemErrorMessage  + '"' + 'message' +'"';
    System.AssertEquals(Constants.getUnknownQueryProblemErrorMessage('message'),Message);
    }'

Answer (score 0):

```
static testmethod void getUnknownQueryProblemErrorMessage()
{
Constants c = new Constants();//instantiate the class
c.getUnknownQueryProblemErrorMessagemethod(); //call the instance method
String message = constants.unknownQueryProblemErrorMessage  + '"' + 'message' +'"';
System.AssertEquals(Constants.getUnknownQueryProblemErrorMessage('message'),Message);
}
```